# can't print "No Mail" if hashmap has nothing to print

Tags: java, hashmap

When I tried to print out the users that do not have any mail in their inbox and to print out "No mail" it does not print out anything but if there's something inside then it will work

The code is here

```
for(String key : items.keySet()) {

    System.out.println("Mail for " + key);
    ArrayList<MailItem> mailBox = items.get(key);
    if(mailBox == null){
        System.out.println("No mail");
    } else {
        for(MailItem item : mailBox){
           System.out.println(item.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

`items` is a hashmap and I'm not suppose to remove the values once it is printed

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean

```
if(mailBox == null || mailBox.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

Be more relaxed:

```
if(mailBox == null || mailBox.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking empty list in first `if` condition.

Change

```
    if(mailBox == null){
```

to

```
    if(mailBox == null || mailBox.size()==0){
```

or

```
    if(mailBox == null || mailBox.isEmpty()){
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to deal with the case where mailBox exists but has no items in it.

e.g.

```
if(mailBox == null || mailBox.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("No mail");
```